# VueJS component ref component is not accessible at all

Tags: vue.js

I don't understand the refs when using in Vue component. It is not working properly.. I have two files

**show.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container fluid class="bg-white" v-if="$refs.chart">
      <b-row class="topTab types">
        <b-col
          :class="{ active: currentTab === index }"
          v-for="(tabDisplay, index) in $refs.chart.tabDisplays"
          :key="index"
        >
          <router-link
            :to="{ query: { period: $route.query.period, tab: index } }"
          >
            {{ tabDisplay }}
          </router-link>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
    <component v-bind:is="currentGame" ref="chart" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    currentGame() {
      return () =>
        import(
          `@/components/Trend/example/Charts/${this.group}/${this.id}/Base.vue`
        );
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

**Base.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    dadsas
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  data: function() {
    return {
      tabDisplays: {
        1: "example1",
        2: "example2",
        3: "example3",
        4: "example4"
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Take note that the second file renders properly showing the dasdas but the `$refs.chart.tabDisplays` is not. It will only show when I change something inside the `<script>` tag like adding `5: "example5"` in the `tabDisplays` data then if I refresh it will be gone again. Basically, I just want to access the computed property of my child component. I am very aware I can use `vuex` but I want to try accessing a component's computed property via `ref`. What is wrong with my `$.refs.chart`?

Comment: Refs are only populated after rendering, not before or during. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref The child component doesn't exist at the point you're trying to access it.

Comment: So what can I do?? Seems like they showed us a technique but did not provide a way how to use it properly on certain cases

Comment: Can you not pass tableDisplays to child component as a prop from parent? And you mentioned that you want to access computer property in child, however tableDisplays isn't computer. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Himanshu, no this case is different. I am using like a dynamic template format so it is the other way around. Basically the tabs that will be displayed is dynamic. It will be based on the route params.. Take note that the `<component>` rendered is different per route params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, refs are only populated after rendering, so you won't have access to them during rendering. This is mentioned in the docs, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref. The child component doesn't exist at the point you're trying to access it. The rendering process is responsible for creating the child components, it all gets a bit circular if you try to access them during that rendering process.

It looks like you've already made several key design decisions here about how to structure your application, such as component boundaries and data ownership, and those decisions are making it difficult to get where you want to be. It's not easy to make concrete suggestions about how to fix that based purely on the code provided.

So instead I will attempt to suggest a minimal change that should fix the immediate problem you're having.

To access the property of the child you're going to need the parent component to render twice. The first time it will create the `chart` and the second time it will have the relevant property available. One way to do this would be to copy the relevant property to the parent after rendering.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container fluid class="bg-white" v-if="tabDisplays">
      <b-row class="topTab types">
        <b-col
          :class="{ active: currentTab === index }"
          v-for="(tabDisplay, index) in tabDisplays"
          :key="index"
        >
          <router-link
            :to="{ query: { period: $route.query.period, tab: index } }"
          >
            {{ tabDisplay }}
          </router-link>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
    <component v-bind:is="currentGame" ref="chart" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return { tabDisplays: null };
  },

  computed: {
    currentGame() {
      return () =>
        import(
          `@/components/Trend/example/Charts/${this.group}/${this.id}/Base.vue`
        );
    },
  },

  mounted () {
    this.tabDisplays = this.$refs.chart.tabDisplays;
  },

  updated () {
    this.tabDisplays = this.$refs.chart.tabDisplays;
  }
};
</script>
```

In the code above I've introduced a `tabDisplays` property and that is then being synced with the child in `mounted` and `updated`. Within the template there's no reference to `$refs` at all.

While this should work I would repeat my earlier point that the 'correct' solution probably involves more significant changes. Syncing data up to a parent like this is not a normal Vue pattern and strongly suggests an architectural failure of some kind.

Comment: This worked but I made some adjustments. In my opinion, it is kinda disappointing that VueJS document suggested an awesome approach but can not be used freely and they did not provide a case solution on their document. I will answer how I did my approach but it is really based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @skirtle's answer. I just made a few tweaks in his answer to produce what I really want

**show.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container fluid class="bg-white" v-if="chart">
      <b-row class="topTab types">
        <b-col
          :class="{ active: currentTab === index }"
          v-for="(tabDisplay, index) in chart.tabDisplays"
          :key="index"
        >
          <router-link
            :to="{ query: { period: $route.query.period, tab: index } }"
          >
            {{ tabDisplay }}
          </router-link>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
    <component v-bind:is="currentGame" ref="chart" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      chart: undefined
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentGame() {
      return () =>
        import(
          `@/components/Trend/高频彩/Charts/${this.group}/${this.id}/Base.vue`
        );
    },
  },
  updated() {
    this.chart = this.$refs.chart;
  }
};
</script>
```